# Replace NaN sequence according to values before and after the sequence

Tags: matlab, nan, fill

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this problem...

I have a vector

`A = [NaN 1 1 1 1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2 2 2 NaN NaN NaN 2 NaN NaN 3 NaN NaN];`

I would like to fill the NaN values according to this logic.

1) if the value that precedes the sequence of NaN is different from the one that follows the sequence => assign half of the NaNs to the first value and half to the second value

2) if the NaN seqence is between 2 equal values => fill the NaN with that value.

A should be then:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (1) 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

I have put one 1 within brakets because I assigned that value to the first half...the sequence of NaNs is odd.

Comment: Could the first element be NaN? If so, what must be the expected output? Similarly what if the last element is NaN?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the question. Yes it could be..I modified my question accordingly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am typing this in my phone, without MATLAB - so there can be some issues. But this should be close:

```
t = 1:numel(A);
Anew = interp1(t(~isnan(A)),A(~isnan(A)),t,'nearest','extrap');
```

Comment: _I am typing this in my phone_: Stack Overflow can be addictive, right? :-)

Comment: Congrats on your 1000 rep, by the way!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use `bwdist` to calculate the index of the nearest non-NaN-neighbor:

```
nanMask = isnan(A);
[~,idx] = bwdist(~nanMask);
A(nanMask) = A(idx(nanMask));
```