# How to interpolate NaN values linearly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, interpolation, nan, linear-interpolation

This is probably a very simple, and frequently asked question, however I tried a lot of solutions, none of them worked for me.

I have different time series which contain NaN's in different places, so I want to obtain a single solution to fill them all.

For example :

```
var1 = [80.2 , 76.5 , NaN , 62.3];
var2 = [NaN , NaN , 100.5 , 102.4];
var3 = [1.2 , 4.7 , NaN, NaN];
```

I just want a simple interpolation code that I can obtain the estimated full data like this :

```
var1_filled = fill_vector(var1);
```

### What I Have Tried :

I tried using [naninterp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8225-naninterp), but since it's cubic, for example var3 goes to the order of 1e4, which I don't want. And if I change the `'cubic'` argument to `'linear'`, then it doesn't handle NaNs.

I also tried to implement a similar function myself, which also does not handle NaNs :

```
dd_x=find(~isnan(dd));
dd_y=dd(~isnan(dd));
yi=interp1(dd_x,dd_y,1:length(dd));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close:

```
t = 1:numel(var1);
var1_filled = interp1(t(~isnan(var1)),var1(~isnan(var1)),t,'linear','extrap');
```

You have to repeat this for each of the variables, since the nan values or not at the same indexes. The extrapolation is needed for `var2` and `var3`.

((This answer is by the way almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387059/4086755) one.))

Comment: Thanks! It worked nice for one variable, please let me see if it works for all my variables, and then I'll accept.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, and I did. It works greatly. Thanks for this quick and accurate solution :)

Comment: It would be nice it the solution could be obtained in one go, but since you have NaN values on the end and beginning of your arrays, this one-go-approach is only possible if and only if you combine them like this: `A = [var2 var1 var3]`.

Comment: Oh thats no problem, I'll just use it with a for loop over all variables.

Comment: You can report for duplicate cases as comments to questions. Reduces burden on SO that way.